# dbowner selected as role shows data with other role doesnt show in iis

Tags: sql, sql-server

thanks for your support its really amazing
iam working on issue with sql and iis,i have created login testB same login iam using in a iis site.
when iam selected db_owner its shows in drop down
[image]

when i remove db_owner from roles in SQL it shows like this

[image]

can you please help me out client doesnt want SA neither db_owner without that i can see in dropdown

or what permission can be denied with db_owner so role can just view/read  data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role you are looking for is called **db_datareader**.  It is a fixed database role that can read/view all data from all user tables.  As you can see in the diagram, it is a subset of the db_owner permission.  ([See reference about other fixed database roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017))

[image]